Print Apache Camel route to Java DSL
Is there a way to print routes in Java DSL?
I found a way to print my Camel routes in XML DSL using:
ModelHelper.dumpModelAsXml(camelContext, routeDefinition);

or in YAML DSL using:
ModelWriter(stringWriter).writeRoutesDefinition(routesDefinition.get());

But I didn't find a way to print them in Java DSL.

No there is no such feature, and its not planned either.

thnx, @Claus!
Generaly i want to convert yaml dsl to java dsl.
Mb, you know some other way to convert yaml route to java route?

No not to Java - you would need to write some tool yourself. But what is the reason for this? Why are you doing this

We want to make a designer based on Karavan, but with java dsl preview feature
